# Vite: How to speed up build with large dependency?

Tags: vite

I'm developing a chrome extension so I need to use `vite build` and can't use `vite dev`.

I'm trying to use the [monaco-editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/). Even when I'm careful to only use a [minimal monaco setup](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/tree/main/samples/browser-esm-webpack-small), build time increases from a nice 0.6s to annoying 5.6s.

Is there any way to speed that up?

What *should* be possible is to create a separate vite configuration only to build the monaco dependency (which doesn't change much), and that provides a `window.setupMonaco()` used by my project, so my project doesn't need to build any monaco code at all. What would be the most elegant way to do that using `vite`?

I've also considered fixing build time by conditionally not including monaco by using `resolve.alias` to create an `@editor` alias so I can provide a non-monaco (faster-to-build) editor implementation based on an environment variable when developing on non-monaco-related code.

I've also tried using some vite options, but they don't seem to make much difference:

```js
// Setting FASTER=1 really doesn't do much
const fasterConfig = process.env.FASTER ?
  {
    sourcemap: false,
    minify: false,
    cleanCssOptions: { sourceMap: false },
    rollupOptions: { treeshake: false },
  } : {}

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  ...fasterConfig,
```